# Scala hashmap of listbuffers

Tags: list, scala, hashmap, defaultdict

I am trying to emulate a defaultdict(list) in Scala (I've already declared scala.collection.mutable.HashMap).

Right now I am trying

```
val d = new HashMap[Int,ListBuffer[Int]](){ override def default(key:Int) = ListBuffer[Int]() }
```

And then to append to a list I try something like:

```
d(integerKey) += integerValToInsertIntoList
```

But nothing seems to work and `d` acts like it's always empty?

Comment: I figured it out I think, I did `val d= new HashMap[Int,ListBuffer[Int]]()` and then when doing the appends, I did `d.getOrElseUpdate(integerKey, new ListBuffer()) += integerValToInsertIntoList` but I have no idea if this is the proper way to do it or if there is a better answer

Comment: I doubt `d(integerKey) += integerValToInsertIntoList` adds `integerKey` to `d`, so each time it returns a new empty `ListBuffer`.

Comment: Well I assume d(integerkey) refers to the listbuffer within the hashmap, and thus += appends the item into the buffer, but I guess I am wrong

Comment: That seems to be a good solution.

Comment: I'll leave this q open in case someone else has a better answer / wants the rep points

Comment: Yes, but each time you add (`+=`) a value to the returned value, you get a new `ListBuffer`, so you add the value to a `ListBuffer` not in the map.

Comment: Are you saying that d(key) is simply referring to a new buffer that isn't related to the actual hashmap object?

Comment: Yes, in case it was not present before.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proper way of implementing this for mutable Maps:

```
val d = new HashMap[Int,ListBuffer[Int]]() {
   override def apply(key: Int) = super.getOrElseUpdate(key, ListBuffer())
}
d(4) append 4
d(5) append 5
scala> d(4)
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(4)
scala> d(5)
res2: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(5)
```

---

#### Note

Using `withDefaultValue` does not work as expected for mutable Maps. It will reuse the same "default" ListBuffer() for all new entries.

```
val d = new HashMap[Int,ListBuffer[Int]]().withDefaultValue(ListBuffer())
d(4) append 4
d(5) append 5
```

In the REPL we see that d(4) (same for d(5)) will hold both new added entries:

```
scala> d(4)
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(4, 5)
scala> d(5)
res2: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(4, 5)
```

Comment: Why would this work? `d(4)` would be always the same `ListBuffer`. If you check, after `d(5) append 44`, it would return both for `d(4)` and `d(5)` (or even `d(0)`) `4, 5, 44`. Check [this fiddle](http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com/gist/5492841dad177d0b0ba1?)

Comment: good catch thanks! I used it so many times with immutable Maps, and I really thought that it would work as expected with mutable Maps as well ... It seems that this mutable implementation reuses the same default value for all new entries.